# ¿Cómo configuro un proyecto maven multi módulo para que un módulo ejecute al otro?

Tags: java, maven

estoy reviviendo un proyecto famoso llamado [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar) y en el proceso de rearquitectura me encontré con el siguiente caso:

La librería tenía el código de demostración como parte de ella y la saqué en un proyecto maven multimódulo de la siguiente manera:

**Restructuración de carpetas**

```
jcalendar (JCalendar-swing)
|
|
----- jcalendar
|
------ jcalendar-demo
```

Mi problema viene en el jcalendar-demo, porque quiero que incluya el jar generado por el módulo jcalendar y que se pueda ejecutar desde línea de comandos.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

Para hacer ejecutable el jar con el plugin de maven llamado `maven-jar-plugin` y para ponerle todas las dependencias referenciadas intenté con el [maven-assembly-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-assembly-plugin).

Mi pom completo de ese módulo:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.github.javatlacati</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcalendar-swing</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>

    </properties>

    <artifactId>jcalendar-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>JCalendar demo</name>
    <description>The JCalendar Component - Demo project</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javatlacati</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <artifactId>looks</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.toedter.calendar.demo.JCalendarDemo</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar dos plugins se puede usar uno solo, el [maven-assembly-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-assembly-plugin) solamente con agregar la configuración que querías para tu jar en este otro plugin.

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

   .
   .
   .
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>

   <mainClass>com.toedter.calendar.demo.JCalendarDemo</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Esto te permitirá crear un jar para correr fácilmente en cualquier lugar mediante el comando `java -jar [minombredearchivo]-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

El pom debería quedar algo así:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.github.javatlacati</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcalendar-swing</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>

    </properties>

    <artifactId>jcalendar-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>JCalendar demo</name>
    <description>The JCalendar Component - Demo project</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javatlacati</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <artifactId>looks</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.toedter.calendar.demo.JCalendarDemo</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```